# how edit toolbar ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I have this code, but the line of toolbar with fontfamily does not show in the editor:

```
<script>
                    var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.editor');
                    for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
                        ClassicEditor.create(allEditors[i],                                                         {
                            toolbar:  [
                                        'source', 'undo', 'redo',
                                        '|', 'heading',
                                        '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor',
                                        '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'code',
                                        '|', 'link', 'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', 'codeBlock', 'image',
                                        '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', 'outdent', 'indent'
                                ]
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

The code works, when I disable the line of bold it disapear, but the line of fontfamily does not show up